# java swing - make the smallest button

Tags: swing, button

Hi
When I create a button in swing it adds a border around my text, thus making my button a bit bigger.
Now, I really need that screen space and what I usually do is create a text item (disabled ) which create much smaller component size (smaller space around my text) and add to it a listner. 
saves space. but awkward. 
Is there a better way to create a tiny button? (when I try to make it smaller it quickly puts a "..." inside though it got room for much more text)

10x

Comment: @userNNNN "..I really need that screen space".  Have you ever considered that your users need a clickable button and a workable GUI?  Perhaps you should consider other strategies, including scroll-bars, and hiding buttons that are not currently relevant.

Comment: well, this is not the case. some software, you just have to fight over screen pixels. but thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to set The Insets narrower...

```
jButton1.setText("jButton1");
jButton1.setMargin(new java.awt.Insets(1, 2, 1, 2));
```

The integer arguments are: **int top, int left, int bottom, int right**

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the size of the button?

`jButton.`[setMinimumSize](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setMinimumSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29)`(new Dimension(width, height))`
`jButton.`[setPreferredSize](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setPreferredSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29)`(new Dimension(width, height))`
`jButton.`[setMaximumSize](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setMaximumSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29)`(new Dimension(width, height))`

You should be able to achieve the desired results using a combination of these methods, along with specifying the margin of your button, which controls the space between the text and the edges, i.e.

`jButton.`[setMargin](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMargin%28java.awt.Insets%29)`(new Insets(top, left, bottom, right))`

Answer (score 0):

If youre using NetBeans GUI-builind this can be achived under the button property "margin" by changing its value to the type "user code" and the value to "new java.awt.Insets(1, 2, 1, 2)"